# Cordova build android fail

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to run a cordova application on an virtual android device I juste created. But during the build I face the following errors :

```
$ cordova run android
Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/User/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home
studio
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
:wrapper

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 7.673 secs
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
(node:24627) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: /Users/User/Sites/testing/cordova/hello/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I'm using Cordova 8.0 and android@~7.0.0

After some research I think this is probably related to gradle, but I can't find if I have missed something to install or a version issue

UPDATE: after a lot of struggle, I tried to install everything needed for cordova on another computer and it seems to be working fine now. I'll tri to figure what is the issue on my computer.

Comment: this is not the answer you are waiting for but for my part, I had to downgrade to pre 6.4.0 for android to be able to build anything with Cordova 8.

Comment: I tried with 6.4.0 and got the same error, with 6.3.0 I have another error :
Execution failed for task ':packageDebug'.
> class org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive overrides final method equals.(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z.

Anyway, yes the point would be to be able to run an app with the latest release.

Comment: You can't, that's my point... I mean https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/